# how to set a value to a current user control from dynamically called user control

Tags: vb.net

I have worked using a tab page so the user can open multiple pages at the same time even with the same menu, I can accomplish this using Devexpress XtraTabControl and a little function like this :

```
    Dim newTab As XtraTabPage = New XtraTabPage
    newTab.Text = "User Account"

    tabData.TabPages.Add(newTab)

    Dim frm = New ucUserAccount()
    frm.Visible = True
    frm.Dock = DockStyle.Fill
    newTab.Controls.Add(frm)
    tabData.TabPages.IndexOf(newTab)
    Dim indexz = tabData.TabPages.IndexOf(newTab)
    tabData.SelectedTabPageIndex = indexz
```

using the above code, user can open the User Control as many time as they want and result like this :

[image: sameform]

if you take a look at the image, there is button "Add" which function is calling another Form to add a user, the function is like this :

```
Private Sub btnAdd_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnAdd.Click
    Form2.show()
End Sub
```

at the form2 I want to add the user and call the `loadData()` function at the current opened User Control, but it always return error reference to non-shared member, like this :

```
Private Sub btnSimpan_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnSimpan.Click
    Dim ID = txtID.Text
    Dim Username = txtUsername.Text
    Dim FullName = txtFullName.Text
    Dim Email = txtEmail.Text
     
    strSQLShared = "xsp_useraccont_createuser '" & Username & "','" & FullName & "','" & Email & "','" & UserLoginShared & "'"
    sqlEksekusiShared(strSQLShared)

    ucUserAccount.loadData() '<----- ERROR HERE "reference to non-shared member" /////////////////

    Clear()


    MsgBox("Data Saved Successfully")
End Sub
```

if using a Form, above code works great without any error, but Forms can only be opened one at the time, so it will not work using a tab page like what I want to do.

what is the proper way to do this using User Control, and how to determine which user control will be updated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The very first thing you should do is learn about default form instances. [Here](http://jmcilhinney.blogspot.com/2009/07/vbnet-default-form-instances.html)'s my own spiel on the subject.

Once you understand how default form instances work, you'll understand why you are wrong to say that forms can only be opened one at a time and why the code you have makes no sense. What you need to do is get the actual instance of that type that you want to use and then use it. I don't use that particular control so I'm not sure exactly what members you would use but, in principle, you need to get the selected page first, then get the user control from that, then use it. That might look something like this:

```vb
Dim selectedTabPage = DirectCast(tabData.SelectedTabPage, XtraTabPage)
Dim userAccount = selectedTabPage.Controls.OfType(Of ucUserAccount)().Single()

userAccount.loadData()
```

Comment: nice works perfectly... I see it works with form too using your guide. hmm now i wonder, which is much more efficient or lighter, User Control or Form ?